# Does anyone have any working code in Python or LabVIEW to get data from the SolisCloud Inverter API?

Tags: python, api, labview, solar

I have a solar installation with a Solis hybrid inverter and access to the SolisCloud API with my own plant info and secret key etc. I want to extract historical data to tell me how much energy the inverter has imported from the grid during 'Economy 7 hours' and 'peak hours' separately between any two historical dates.

For now, I am looking for any code I can understand that successfully accesses the SolisCloud API.

I asked Solis for working code examples in Python and they sent me a [Java code fragment](https://ginlong-product.oss-cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/templet/Authorization.java) - which I don't know how to use (I am totally unfamiliar with Java - I don't know how to write any code that would actually call this).

So what I am looking for is maybe a Python (or LabVIEW or C) program which is complete and does any simple operation (like extract data from a particular date and time) that I can use with my own secret key etc. to test that I am communicating with the inverter OK.....

Does anyone have any code they would be willing to share or know where I can find something working as a starting point?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.